# I am trying to post image on Facebook using asp.net but I am getting exception as Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

**C# Code**

> I am using ASPSnippets.FaceBookAPI to upload image on Facebook in local machine I get exception as Thread was being aborted and if I try on live domain it says "Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "gfafsa";
    FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "bdhsafvhj";
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {

                if (Session["File"] != null)
                {
                    FaceBookConnect.PostFile(code, "me/photos", (HttpPostedFile)Session["File"], Session["Message"].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    data.Add("message", Session["Message"].ToString());
                    FaceBookConnect.Post(code, "me/feed", data);
                }


                Session["File"] = null;
                Session["Message"] = null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}

protected void lbtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            Session["File"] = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        Session["Message"] = txtCaption.Text;
       FaceBookConnect.Authorize("user_photos,publish_actions", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]);
        Response.Redirect("", false);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real Facebook API Key and Secret.